# How to swich on contextLoadListener depends on spring profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-profiles

I need to execute code before application will be started.

I have wrote the following listener(registered in web.xml):

```
Profile("test")
public class H2Starter extends ContextLoaderListener {


    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {    
        System.out.println("invoked")
    }    

}
```

I expect that listener will be invoked only if `test` profile is activte.
But it invokes always. How to fix this behviour ?

Answer (score 2):

According to documentation `@Profile` annotation can be applied only to `@Component` or `@Configuration`. Anyway you can't get information about profiles in ContextLoaderListener, because there is not ApplicationContext loaded yet. If you would like to invoke your code at application start, my suggestion is to create `ApplicationListener` and listen to `ContextRefreshEvent`:

```
@Component
public class CustomContextListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent contextRefreshedEvent) {
        Environment environment = contextRefreshedEvent.getApplicationContext().getEnvironment();
        if(environment.acceptsProfiles("test")){
            System.out.print("Test profile is active");
        }
    }
}
```

First time this listener will be invoked **after** application gets initialized.
If you going to get profile information **before** context was initilized, you can create new context loader:

```
public class ProfileContextListener extends ContextLoaderListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        if(isProfileActive("test", event.getServletContext())){
            System.out.println("Profile is active");
        }
    }

    private boolean isProfileActive(String profileName, ServletContext context) {
        String paramName = "spring.profiles.active";            
        //looking in web.xml
        String paramValue = context.getInitParameter(paramName);
        if(paramValue==null) {
            //if not found looking in -D param
            paramValue = System.getProperty(paramName);
        };
        if(paramValue==null) return false;
        String[] activeProfileArray = paramValue.split(",");
        for(String activeProfileName : activeProfileArray){
            if(activeProfileName.trim().equals(profileName)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

To activate needed profile you have add to your web.xml special spring environment property - `spring.profiles.active`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>default,test</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Or you can set profile throw -D jvm-option

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=default,test
```

Note, that you can add multiple profile names separated by comma.

Comment: after initialization is late

Comment: for me **context.getInitParameter("spring.profiles.active")** always returns null. I start application like this: **mvn clean install jetty:run -Dspring.profiles.active=test**

Comment: @gstackoverflow, because to get param from jvm option we have to use System.getProperty(). Code have been updated.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding the spring profiles only applicable for the configuration

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

seems profile annotation is not applicable for the scenario that you mentioned.